# Google Speech Recognition - numbers only

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, speech-synthesis

Is there a way to limit the grammar to numbers only in either dictation mode or in constructing a custom grammar XML file? Obviously I can't enter all the numbers into the XML, but there has to be an easy way.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525503/api-or-sdk-to-make-speech-recognition-only-for-numbers-between-1-and-10000/