# API or SDK to make speech recognition only for numbers (between 1 and 10000)?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

I need a specialized solution optimized to detect numbers between 1 and 1000 to be used on a smartphone.
Best solution would be to have this SDK working offline.
Any idea ?
I do not find any configuration with Google Speech or Amazon Transcribe to allow "number only"

Comment: I up-voted this. I have a similar need. I am working on an application for doing voice entry inventory (off line). The user would state a predefined keyword, followed by a number.

Comment: This is not a coding related question. There is no effort shown (even for finding and implementation). This is simply not the correct place to put this question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite right to strictly expect numbers from people, they usually say many things like "i don't know" or "wait a bit" even if you ask them for numbers. You will harm the experience significantly.

You have to analyze the recognition result intelligently and even if non-number is recognized you have to act accordingly.

To improve accuracy for numbers specifically you can use [word hint feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009619/google-cloud-speech-api-word-hints/43975192#43975192) of Google Speech API. Just add digits and other required words as a hint and Google will recognize them much more accurately. Amazon also has this feature they call it "[custom vocabulary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/transcribe/latest/dg/API_CreateVocabulary.html)".

If you want to use an offline API you can certainly try [Kaldi](https://kaldi-asr.org). You can [adapt Kaldi vocabulary](https://github.com/srvk/lm_build) with numbers to improve the accuracy, it will be much better than Google API.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found for this is to pass in [class tokens](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation#class_tokens) as the phrase to your google request. This allows you to specify common sets of specific values to use as the dictionary. For example passing in ["$OOV_CLASS_DIGIT_SEQUENCE"] allows you to filter for digits of any length.